# Make a div like google

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to make a `div` like the one in screen shot I have attached.

It opens when we click on Apps and closed when click on any where else on the page. Especially the part outlined in green and gray.

I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.. just an idea how to achieve it which I have outlined in green part.

Comment: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/ - go for it!

Comment: did you even try to read the source code of the page ? or try to reproduce it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should elaborate what you want? Do you want a popup or an arrow like one shown in the screenshot?

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/F47uy/

**CSS**:

```
#arrow{
     border-left: 15px dashed transparent;
     border-right: 15px dashed transparent;
     border-bottom: 15px dashed grey;
     margin-left:200px;
     width:0;
     height:0;
}
 #box{
     background:grey;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
}
```